# Can anyone translate the handwriting on the front and back of this postcard?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, handwriting

Can anyone translate the writing on the back of this postcard?

[image: Back]

[image: Front] [image: Front]

Comment: Is the translation provided by @Beta sufficient or do you need this in English?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Such a translation would be off-topic, and we don't want to violate the rules, do we?

Comment: @Beta I was just irritated by OP's request for _translation_ instead of _transcription_, but I admit that's nitpicking :)

Comment: Handwriting is so hard to read...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an attempt at transcribing the writing on the back. No translation though, since that would be off-topic:

d. 25. Dezember 1928
In treuem Gedanken! Besten dank für deinen  Brf. (=Brief?). der heute kam u. dankbaren Jubel bei Jung u. Alt auslöste, besonders auch, weil es unserem Charly wieder gut geht. Brf. folgt! Herzlich Mama.
Kuss! Muck(?) mit deidei(?) u. Mausi.
Beste Weihnachtsgrüße von Papa.
Herzlichen Gruß + Verg(elts)-Gott (Unreadable name: "Inntally"??)

On the front it says: Flughafen-Hôtel

Comment: hm, das 'Muda' sieht für mich aber eher wie Much oder Muck aus.

Comment: @arved ja viellecht, aber das hat auch keinen Sinn...

Comment: Könnte es auch "Gedenken" heißen?

Comment: @RolandIllig ja, eigentlich sieht es nach einem "e" aus, aber der "a" in "dank" und "dankbaren" so sieht auch so aus.als wäre es ein "e". Ist es trotzdem nicht.

Comment: Ich lese da auch ein "Muck"- wird wohl der Kosename sein, vllt für ein Kind. Das "deidei"  klingt nach einer Wortschöpfung von diesem Kind (vllt als Name für sein Geschwister oder Haustier)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am having dinner with "Charly's" son tonight. Will let you know if he can shed some light on the "muck"!